# invalid object name 'VchReceipt'

Tags: sql-server

what is solution of this...

Invalid object name 'VchReceipt'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'VchReceipt'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'VchReceipt'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1950890
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4846875
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2392
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows() +157
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout) +197
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read() +9
   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping) +78
   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue) +164
   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords) +353
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +164
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +287
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet) +94
   amitek.cldata.usingdataadapter(String Str) +208
   amitek.mecollection.loaddgme() +849
   amitek.mecollection.drpbranch_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) +13
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() +134
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents() +165
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1485

my code is...............
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

alter FUNCTION [dbo].[getAmountByMeCode]
(@meCode varchar(100),@frmDate datetime,@todate datetime)
RETURNS numeric
AS
    BEGIN
        Declare @result numeric
        select  @result=IsNull(SUM(vr.cAmount),0)  from VchReceipt as vr,Orders as o
where vr.cGroup='Clients' and vr.cLogNo=o.cOrderId and o.cEmpId=@meCode
and vr.cDate>=@frmDate and vr.cDate<@todate
    RETURN @result
    END

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You either don't have an object called `VchReceipt` in the default schema of the calling user (and dbo schema) or don't have suitable permissions to select from it.